# Do gangster-themed Madoka subtitles really exist?

Tags: madoka-magica, meme

I've often come across gangster-themed Madoka subtitled screenshots, but I haven't been able to find any solid evidence that they exist. Sometimes the characters are referred to as ***Swagdoka*** and ***Homubro*** instead of their actual names *Madoka* and *Homura*

The images below are sample of these gangster subtitles, and are in differing scenes throughout the show.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm not asking for any links, I was just wondering if these subtitles actually exist or if it's mostly internet rumours and only some scenes have been 'gangster-ized'.

Comment: afta sum googlin' it's become apparent dat dis here fakesub consist of popular separate phrases changed a lil' bit to fit the context of the anime.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, after a while of researching this, it appears that someone had taken a subtitle file and run it through [Gizoogle's Translation](http://www.gizoogle.net/textilizer.php) site.

Gizoogle is a parody of Google based off of Snoop Dogg's lingo

What this does is translates sentences such as:

> Madoka and Homura are best witch friends forever.

into Gangsta slang:

> Madoka n' Homura is dopest witch playaz forever n' shit.

The subtitles have not been published online, whoever created them merely posted screenshots. But if you had an original subtitle file, you could replicate it easily enough by using the same process.